# How to create login / registerform template with auth_tank/codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

Struggling to figure out how to achieve this. I want a login/registerform on same page when using `tank_auth` in CodeIgniter.

I was thinking of having something like this in my members controller (which extends My_Controller which extends Auth).

```
class Members extends My_Controller (

    public function login()
    {
            //Already loggedin, do nothing
            if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
                    return;
            }
            $this->view_data['login_by_username'] = true;
            $this->view_data['login_by_email'] = false;
            $this->view_data['show_captcha'] = false;

            $this->view_data['login_form'] = $this->load->view('auth/login_form', $this->view_data, TRUE);
            $this->view_data['register_form'] = $this->load->view('auth/register_form', $this->view_data, TRUE);

            $this->v('members/login_register'); //In this view $login_form and $register_form is rendered
    }

}
```

When I go to that page (localhost/members/login) the members/login-view is shown as expected, but in the action of the form for loginform it says:

```
http://localhost/members/login
```

Therefore when I click "Login-button" then it just calls members/login and that's not what I want. I want the action to be auth/login, but I still want to use my own template.

I hope you guys understand what I mean.... Please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong/thinking of this incorrectly.

**UPATE:**
In the actual template (members/login_register) it looks like this:

```
<div class="column">
<?php echo $login_form;?>
</div>
<div class="column>
<?php echo $register_form;?>
</div>
```

Maybe what I want to achieve is not possible?

Comment: In your actual form view, what did you give for the action attribute?

Comment: @Patrick - I haven't defined any action attribute, just echoed out the variables $login_form and $register_form. See update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Master View

---

You should use a Master view as a wrapper for your content.
That way you can easily pass in partial views(although not required)
However it will keep things neat. It also allows for easier control over
Admin/User Dashboards and your frontend.

## Main Controller

---

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $template;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->template = "master/template"; //views/master/template
    }
}
```

To change it for an admin template(as an example of flexibility) you simply need to change it 
the variable in the __constructor

```
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->template = "master/admin/template"; //views/master/admin/template
    }
}
```

## Partial View(s)

---

Partial views can be used directly in other views.
You don't need a controller to call them.
These views are just stored in the buffer when they are 
loaded by the loader class `$this->load->view('', '', true)`

A common approach is to create a folder inside /views called "partials".
This is where you would keep all you re-usable views(such as forms/widgets).

## The Views(/views/partials/login_form)

```
<div>
  <?php echo form_open('members/login', array('id'=>'login-form'))
</div>
```

## The Views(/views/partials/signup_form)

```
<div>
  <?php echo form_open('members/signup', array('id'=>'signup-form'))
</div>
```

## The Views(members/index)

You can then combine the views

```
<div class="signup-form">
  <?php echo $this->load->view('partials/signup_form')
</div>

<div class="login-form">
  <?php echo $this->load->view('partials/login_form')
</div>
```

## Login / Signup

In your members class you can create one method to show 
the register/login form and then create methods to handle each of them individually.

```
class Members extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->load->view('members/login_register');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
            return $this->index();
        }

        // form validation passed Ask Tank Auth 
        // to log the user in
        $tank->auth->login();
    }

    public function signup()
    {
        if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
            return $this->index();
        }

        // form validation passed Ask Tank Auth 
        // to register 
        $tank->auth->register();
    }
}
```